# Django model from create a new record instead of updating old one

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model, record

I am beginner in Django. My issue is that I updating my record but it's adding a new record instead of updating old one.

Where did I go wrong?

**views.py**

```
class EditProduct(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stock/editproduct.html'

    def get(self, request, product_id):
        productedit = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        data=Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        form = EditProductForm(instance=data)
        args = {'form':form, 'productedit':productedit}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request, product_id):
        form = EditProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            productadded = form.save(commit=False)
            productadded.saler =  request.user
            productadded.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            productadded.save()
            return redirect('stock')
        else:
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: use UpdateView instead of template view, that will be more easy for you

Comment: @bmons just change the templateview to UpdateView?? or need to some functionality also?

Comment: no, before changing check the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

Comment: Your form is a form for a new instance, you need to pass it the **instance** you're updating when you want the form to update an existing instance (`form = EditProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product_to_update)`). Same as you did in the `get()` method.

Comment: @dirkgroten its showing my this error 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'concrete_fields'

Comment: you need to show us the code that produces the error and the full error trace.

Comment: @dirkgroten```     def post(self, request, product_id):
        data = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        form = EditProductForm(instance=data)
        form = EditProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=form)
        if form.is_valid(): ```

Comment: wait why do you define `form` twice???? just `form = EditProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=data)` as I mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming stock is the name of the app/folder that contains views.py, models.py, url.py.

views.py see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) for documentation of UpdateViews.

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.utils import timezone
from stock.models import Product
from stock.forms import EditProductForm 

Class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = EditProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('stock:product_list')
    template_name = 'stock/editproduct.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.saler =  self.request.user
        form.instance.pub_date = timezone.now()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
from stock import views

app_name = 'stock'
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/update/<int:pk>', views.ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product_update'),
    path('product/list', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list'
]
```

The below snippet can be added to the html of the product page you want to update, this is generally the product details page generated by the details views class or function.

On that page add a button to take you to the update page passing in the id of the product you want to update.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect" href="{% url 'stock:product_update' pk=product.pk %}"> Update product</a>
```